# Django App Deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk throws 404?

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a sample application on AWS. My folder structure:

```
eb_django_app
├── .ebextensions
│   └── 01-django_eb.config
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│   └── config.yml
├── predictfare
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── predictfare
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── wsgi.pyc
│   │   
│   └── templates
│       └── base.html
└── requirements.txt
```

My 01-django_eb.config:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "predictfare.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/predictfare:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "predictfare/predictfare/wsgi.py"
```

My config.yml:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: faremagus-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:

  application_name: faremagus
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Python 2.7
  default_region: us-west-2
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: null
```

Logs Show : `Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/predictfare/predictfare`

Mostly followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) tutorial. When I run `eb open` I see 404 in the browser. What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like your application didn't deploy successfully. What is the application state displayed in the Elastic Beanstalk console? Are there errors in the server log? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: The logs have `Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/predictfare/predictfare` Is the path wrong? Should I change it ?